# Linq with datatable with two counts c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, datatable

I would like to have two different counts in a single query; I wrote it with SQL Server with the `COUNT` function as

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN Status = 'opened' THEN 1 ELSE NULL)
```

which returns my desired count.

However, in the current situation, I have datatable and am not sure if the above two counts are possible in Linq.

My data is as below.

```
Email      Status 
------------------
email1     opened
email1     opened
email2     clicked
email2     clicked
email2     clicked
email1     clicked
email2     opened
```

The output needs to be:

```
Email      Opened      Clicked
-------------------------------
email1      2             1
email2      1             3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using C# Linq try something like this:

```
var test =  context.stats.GroupBy(x=> x.Email).Select(groupedBy=> new {
            Email = groupedBy.FirstOrDefault().Email,
            Opened = groupedBy.Where(y=> y.Status == "opened").Count(),
            Clicked = groupedBy.Where(y=> y.Status == "clicked").Count()
        });
```

Comment: @k-s if my suggestion/code helped you in achieving your target do let me know or if you had to make changes to this Linq do add it in the comment here to help others.

Comment: Use  `groupedBy.Key` instead of  `groupedBy.FirstOrDefault().Email`

Answer (score 1):

You  want a pivot table.  See code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;


namespace ConsoleApplication40
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Email", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Status", typeof(string));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "email1", "opened"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "email1", "opened" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "email2", "clicked" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "email2", "clicked" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "email2", "clicked" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "email1", "clicked" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "email2", "opened" });


            string[] statusTypes = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("Status")).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
            var groups = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Email")).ToList();

            DataTable pivot = new DataTable();
            pivot.Columns.Add("Email",typeof(string));
            foreach(string statusType in statusTypes)
            {
                pivot.Columns.Add(statusType, typeof(int));
            }

            foreach(var group in groups)
            {
                DataRow row = pivot.Rows.Add();
                row["Email"] = group.Key;
                foreach(string statusType in statusTypes)
                {
                    row[statusType] = group.Where(x => x.Field<string>("Status") == statusType).Count();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works however, I wanted to use LINQ with conditional COUNT as in MSSQL. Multiple counts in one select query.

Comment: var query = from row in table.AsEnumerable()
            group row by row.Field<string>("Email") into sales
            orderby sales.Status
            select new
            {
                Email = sales.Email,
                CountOfStatusOPENED = sales.Count()
            };

Comment: Above type of logic query returns only Open click count.

Comment: You would need to group by the status field to get each status type count.